# AKS: Logging into worker nodes and get Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

AKS- Can't log into one of the worker nodes (VM). I assigned the public IP as per https://gist.github.com/tsaarni/624d5406e442f08fe11083169c059a68 but still no luck. I get the error below:

> JohnDoeMac:.kube john_doe$ ssh azureuser@52.191.195.250
> Permission denied (publickey).

Here subscription ID looks like: e84ff951-xxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Please try to use `-i` to specify the private key to SSH it.

Comment: How to find my private key?

Answer (score 3):

if you create AKS from Azure portal, you can specify the user name of VM.

at that case, user name is not **azureuser** any more

you can find out the user name and public key from Azure portal

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> sushainMac:.kube sushain_chhangani$ ssh azureuser@52.191.195.250
>   Permission denied (publickey).

Please find your private key then use this script to SSH:

```
ssh azureuser@52.191.195.250 -i ~/.ssh/<your private key>
```

**Update**:

When we use CLI 2.0 to create AKS, we can find the key here:

[image]

**Update2**:

Reset public key here:

[image]

Comment: How to find my private key?

Comment: @codeRelix how do you create this AKS, like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough)?  `az aks create --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myK8sCluster --node-count 1 --generate-ssh-keys`? Or Portal?

Comment: @codeRelix we can find the private key in `~/.ssh`, please check it:)

Comment: @codeRelix maybe your key in this folder `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, please try to SSH it with this command `ssh azureuser@52.191.195.250 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Comment: @codeRelix How many keys in your `~/.ssh`? could you please try them?

Comment: There has to be an easier wa

Comment: @codeRelix we can use `ssh-keygen` to get new public key and private key, then use Azure portal to reset public Key, then use new private key to SSH it.

Comment: @codeRelix Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: @codeRelix does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: @codeRelix Does reset public key works for you? please let me know if you need more help:)